# Video board for 2k at 144Hz

Tags: graphics-cards, displays, intel

- i7 5820k
- Mother: x99A
- Display: C27J50

I currently have a rx470 and I still can't run the maximum refresh rate at that resolution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should look to buy a NVIDIA [**GTX 1080ti**](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/) or [**RTX 2080ti**](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/20-series/)

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/anl1ln/which_gpu_for_2k_144hz_gaming/) Reddit post will help you.

**IMPORTANT**: You should check if your MotherBoard accepts that Video Cards and if there's space inside the case.

Comment: But in the specs it says: Maximum Digital Resolution2 > 7680x4320@60Hz
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1080-ti/

Comment: This card can run 7680x4320 at 60Hz, but 144Hz at lower resolutions.

Comment: How about a GTX 1660 Ti?

Comment: GTX 1660 Ti is such a good card, but I didn't found any post / docs about 2K at 144Hz.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a Ryzen 5 1600 + GTX 1080 setup. I'm getting about 100fps in most games at 1440p165hz.

So if you really want to push 144fps, I would recommend getting a 1080ti or better.

- GTX 1080ti
- RTX 2080 (Super)
- RTX 2080ti (Super)

You **might** be able to get away with a 2070 (Super), but I would get one of the above.